# IMAP using c# - AE.Net.Mail Set Gmail Flags

Tags: c#, flags

I'm using the AE.Net.Mail to get emails from a Gmail account, so far so good.
One of my requirements is to put a special gmail flag, at the end of my process.

You can see how the stars works at : http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/add-extra-stars-for-better-gmail-sorting-1681334535

Here is my code:

```
//Get msgs.
Messages = imap.SearchMessages(condition2); 

foreach (Lazy<AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage> message in this.Messages)
{
     imap.AddFlags("Seen", message.Value);
     imap.AddFlags("\\Seen", message.Value);
     imap.AddFlags("\\Flagged", message.Value); 
     imap.AddFlags("green-check", message.Value);
```

I'm expecting to have the email marked with the green-check star, until this point the mail is marked with the yellow-star (flagged), I'm missing something?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you can't set this as an IMAP flag. Most likely you need to use GMail's LABELS extension which is probably not supported by AE.Net.Mail.

You can, however, use my [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library to manipulate labels on GMail.

http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MailKit_MailFolder_AddLabels.htm
http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MailKit_MailFolder_RemoveLabels.htm
http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MailKit_MailFolder_SetLabels.htm

To request the labels on a batch of messages, you can do:

```
var items = folder.Fetch (uids, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.GMailLabels);
foreach (var item in items) {
    Console.WriteLine ("message {0} has the following labels: {1}", item.UniqueId,
        item.GMailLabels != null ? string.Join (", ", item.GMailLabels) : "None");
}
```